# How to get true path of file in file picker in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

How to get true file path in file_picker?

I'm getting examples only the cach path and the method's return I've looked for several examples but I haven't had success, it may be some other package besides file_picker , if anyone has an example.

I'm getting examples only the cah path and the method's return I've looked for several examples but I haven't had success, it may be some other package besides file_picker , if anyone has an example.

[image]

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FilePickerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _FilePickerDemoState createState() => _FilePickerDemoState();
  }
 Future<void> deleteFile(File file) async {
 try {
  if (await file.exists()) {
  await file.delete();
   }
   } catch (e) {
    // Error in getting access to the file.
     }
     }
      class _FilePickerDemoState extends State<FilePickerDemo> {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    String? _fileName;
    List<PlatformFile>? _paths;
String? _directoryPath;
String? _extension;
bool _loadingPath = false;
bool _multiPick = false;
FileType _pickingType = FileType.any;
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
String? get filePath => null;
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller.addListener(() => _extension = _controller.text);
}
void _openFileExplorer() async {
setState(() => _loadingPath = true);
try {
  _directoryPath = null;
  _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: _pickingType,
    allowMultiple: _multiPick,
    allowedExtensions: (_extension?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
        ? _extension?.replaceAll(' ', '').split(',')
        : null,

  ))
      ?.files;
var  A = _paths;

} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
} catch (ex) {
  print(ex);
}
if (!mounted) return;
setState(() {
  _loadingPath = false;
  print(_paths!.first.extension);
  _fileName =
  _paths != null ? _paths!.map((e) => e.name).toString() : '...';
   });
   }
   void _clearCachedFiles() {
  FilePicker.platform.clearTemporaryFiles().then((result) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: result! ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      content: Text((result
          ? 'Temporary files removed with success.'
          : 'Failed to clean temporary files')),
      ),
        );
       });
     }
    void _selectFolder() {
    FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath().then((value) {
  setState(() => _directoryPath = value);
   });
   }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('File Picker example app'),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: DropdownButton<FileType>(
                      hint: const Text('LOAD PATH FROM'),
                      value: _pickingType,
                      items: <DropdownMenuItem<FileType>>[
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('FROM AUDIO'),
                          value: FileType.audio,
                        ),
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('FROM IMAGE'),
                          value: FileType.image,
                        ),
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('FROM VIDEO'),
                          value: FileType.video,
                        ),
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('FROM MEDIA'),
                          value: FileType.media,
                        ),
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('FROM ANY'),
                          value: FileType.any,
                        ),
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: const Text('CUSTOM FORMAT'),
                          value: FileType.custom,
                        ),
                      ],
                      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        _pickingType = value!;
                        if (_pickingType != FileType.custom) {
                          _controller.text = _extension = '';
                        }
                      })),
                ),
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100.0),
                  child: _pickingType == FileType.custom
                      ? TextFormField(
                    maxLength: 15,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                    controller: _controller,
                    decoration:
                    InputDecoration(labelText: 'File extension'),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                  )
                      : const SizedBox(),
                ),
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 200.0),
                  child: SwitchListTile.adaptive(
                    title:
                    Text('Pick multiple files', textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                    onChanged: (bool value) =>
                        setState(() => _multiPick = value),
                    value: _multiPick,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => _openFileExplorer(),
                        child: const Text("Open file picker"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => _selectFolder(),
                        child: const Text("Pick folder"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => _clearCachedFiles(),
                        child: const Text("Clear temporary files"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => _loadingPath
                      ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                      : _directoryPath != null
                      ? ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Directory path'),
                    subtitle: Text(_directoryPath!),
                  )
                      : _paths != null
                      ? Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    height:
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
                    child: Scrollbar(
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          itemCount:
                          _paths != null && _paths!.isNotEmpty
                              ? _paths!.length
                              : 1,
                          itemBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            final bool isMultiPath =
                                _paths != null && _paths!.isNotEmpty;
                            final String name = 'File $index: ' +
                                (isMultiPath
                                    ? _paths!
                                    .map((e) => e.name)
                                    .toList()[index]
                                    : _fileName ?? '...');
                            final path = _paths!
                                .map((e) => e.path)
                                .toList()[index]
                                .toString();

                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                name,
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(path),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          const Divider(),
                        )),
                  )
                      : const SizedBox(),
                ),
                ],
               ),
              ),
             )),
             ),
      );
          }
           }
```

Comment: you cannot get that true path, sorry